# Can browser detect when the browser is running on Foreground or Background mode?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser, visibility

I want to know that when I used multiples types of software on my computer, the browser can detect the others software is running or to?

And also can the browser handle that the browser is running in the background when I use another software.

Or when I used `alt+tab` to switch software, Is it possible for the browser to detect.

Comment: The browser can certainly detect this. Why do you care? Are you asking whether javascript from inside a website displayed in the browser can detect this?

Comment: The browser can detect this. Browser extensions can also detect this with basic permissions. Additionally, pages can listen to certain DOM events to detect when they are no longer in focus. This is not an exhaustive list, but may give you some hints.

Comment: Can browser detect when switching to another software from the browser? @Bergi

Comment: Can I handle extension from raw JS code? @zr0gravity7

Comment: @MijanurRahman Again, what do you mean by "from the browser"? A browser is just an application like any other, and yes, the OS (window manager) provides a way to detect that. But you're not implementing a browser, are you? What are you trying to do, what is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: Basically, I want to know when a user switched from the browser to any other software like `VLC Media player. Is the browser can detect this? @Bergi

Comment: I am trying to develop an `Exam Management System` where I want to know the user is passed away from the browser or not when giving the question answers.

Comment: Do you have any other idea to detect users is left the browser? @Bergi, please.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API):

```js
var visibilityChange;
if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") { // Opera 12.10 and Firefox 18 and later support
  visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
  visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
  visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
}
//^different browsers^

document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, function(){
  console.log("Visibility changed at "+new Date());
}, false);
```

Comment: Can this answer detect when switching to another software from the browser?

Comment: I used this function in componentDidMount when I use ReactJs. But it can only detect when I switch one tab to another using browser.

Comment: @MijanurRahman That's weird... I'll investigate.

Comment: Ok, Thanks a lot. Have any other processes on how to use visibility API into ReactJs?

Comment: Did you get any answers? @Spectric